# Route only when subdomain exist in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

i would like to do sth like this if subdomain is in url:

```
http://example.com/                 -> index.php   
http://hello.example.com/           -> profile.php?subdomain=hello  
http://whatever.example.com/        -> profile.php?subdomain=whatever  
http://example.com/world            -> world.php   
http://example.com/world/test       -> world.php?id=test
http://example.com/sth              -> sth.php   
http://example.com/sth/test2        -> sth.php?id=test2
http://hello.example.com/world/test -> profile.php?subdomain=hello
```

And for other files:

```
RewriteRule ^dodaj_artykul dodaj_artykul.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logowanie logowanie.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rejestracja rejestracja.php [L]
RewriteRule ^wyloguj wyloguj.php [L]


RewriteRule ^kategorie/([^-]+)$ kategorie.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^kategorie/$ kategorie.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kategorie$ kategorie.php [L]
```

If subdomain exist, everything is routed to "profile.php?subdomain=hello"
if isn't exist normal "RewriteRule ^kategorie/([^-]+)$ kategorie.php?id=$1 [L]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this above your other rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^profile\.php$ /profile.php?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: hmm, i have "500 Internal Server Error"